# MySQL query - cannot determine how to write specific query

Tags: mysql

I simply cannot figure out how I should write my MySQL query to get the correct result.

I have a table which contains the following structure:

[image]

I need to write a query which returns a total count of all distinct `ronumbers` which contain the following parameters:

1) Must have a `serviceID` of 1

2) Must also have a `serviceID` greater than 1

3) The `serviceID`'s that are greater than 1 MUST ALL have a decsvc of 1

4) If #3 is anything other than decsvc of 1, that ronumber is disqualified

In simple terms, return a count of all distinct ronumbers that have a serviceID of 1 and `serviceID`(s) greater than 1 that are ONLY declined services (`decsvc = 1`).

I have tried the following queries:

1)

```
$query = "SELECT a.ronumber FROM servicerendered_welr a LEFT JOIN
servicerendered_welr b ON (a.ronumber = b.ronumber) 
WHERE a.serviceID > 1 AND a.decsvc = 1 AND a.addsvc = 0 AND a.dealerID = 
$dealerID 
AND b.serviceID = 1 GROUP BY a.ronumber";
```

2)

```
$query = "SELECT ronumber FROM servicerendered_welr 
WHERE addsvc = 0 AND dealerID = $dealerID AND ronumber IN 
(SELECT ronumber FROM servicerendered_welr WHERE decsvc = 1 AND dealerID =
$dealerID AND ronumber IN 
(SELECT ronumber FROM servicerendered_welr WHERE serviceID > 1 AND dealerID
= $dealerID AND ronumber IN
(SELECT ronumber FROM servicerendered_welr WHERE serviceID = 1 and dealerID
= $dealerID) 
GROUP BY ronumber) 
GROUP BY ronumber)
GROUP BY ronumber";
```

These both return the same result set.  The results return `ronumber`(s) 12 and 16 ([see servicerendered_welr table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIern.jpg)).

[image]

My goal would be to have the query return only `ronumber` 12, pertaining to the above stipulations.  As you can see, `ronumber` 16 does meet some of the qualifications, BUT it has `serviceID`'s greater than 1 that have a `decsvc = 0`, and this is unacceptable.

It is obvious that the query is returning ANYTHING that has a `serviceID` of 1, AND a `serviceID` greater than 1, and at least one `serviceID` greater than 1 with a  `decsvc = 1` (and thus it is not ruling out the other `decsvc = 0` items).

Maybe I need to delve into virtual tables?

Please see my sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e45c/3 .

Comment: How can you have something that "MUST" have ServiceId as 1 and also greater than 1?

Comment: kinda lost me on that one so we vanish

Comment: can you post a dump, that i can create it local

Comment: He means that one of the **other** rows with the same `ronumber` has a serviceId > 1

Comment: Sorry Bernd, I tried to post a dump but I was unable to do so.  I am new to  stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm adding another solution to the mix, one without group bys and having. I would use the [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) clause with subqueries. You essentially want ronumbers that have serviceid=1 and exists at least 1 record where serviceid> 1 and decsvc=1 and does not exist any record where serviceid> 1 and decsvc<> 1:

```
select count(distinct s1.ronumber) from servicerendered_welr s1
where s1.serviceid=1
and exists (select 1 from servicerendered_welr s2 where s2.ronumber=s1.ronumber and s2.serviceid> 1 and s2.decsvc=1)
and not exists (select 1 from servicerendered_welr s3 where s3.ronumber=s1.ronumber and s3.serviceid> 1 and s3.decsvc=0)
```

Comment: Shadow, thank you so much for your input;  however I could only get this query to return one row from my table whereas there should have been 7 (in the case where I tested this).

Comment: My query IS expected to return 1 row only: the number of distinct ronums that meet your criteria. This was the question you asked: "I need to write a query which returns a total count of all distinct ronumbers which contain the following parameters". The answer you accepted stricktly speaking does not answer the above question.

Comment: If you want the list of ronumbers instead of their count, then replace count(distinct s1.ronumber) with distinct s1.ronumber.

Comment: Thank you @Shadow, sorry for my error.  That is my fault for not executing the correct fetch instruction. I will run this again!

Comment: thank you.  I ran the results again and your query also returned exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for you input!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to understand but I think I get what you are trying to do. There is a link to a table you haven't included but I've removed it from the query since it is just part of the WHERE condition. What should work for you is the following:

```
SELECT

a.ronumber

FROM servicerendered_welr a WHERE 

serviceId = 1
AND
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM servicerendered_welr b WHERE b.serviceId > 1 AND b.decsvc = 1 AND b.ronumber = a.ronumber) =
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM servicerendered_welr c WHERE c.serviceId > 1 AND c.ronumber = a.ronumber)
```

Comment: Greg,  thank you so much.  I tried your query and it solved my problem perfectly.  Wow you are really good!!

Comment: Greg, I had to change the answer acceptance to @Shadow, as his/her answer included only those items with serviceID = 1 AND a serviceID > 1, instead of also those items which have ONLY serviceID = 1.  My actual need turned out to be exactly what you offered.  I did in fact additionaly need those that had only serviceID = 1, but unfortunately my original question stated that I MUST have both criterion met.  Is there a way that I can give you points even though I accepted another answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.ronumber) AS ronumber_count
FROM servicerendered_weir AS a
JOIN (SELECT ronumber, COUNT(*) AS count, SUM(IF(decsvc = 1, 1, 0)) AS decsvc1_count
      FROM servicerendered_weir
      WHERE serviceID > 1
      GROUP BY ronumber
      HAVING count = decsvc1_count) AS b
    ON a.ronumber = b.ronumber
WHERE a.serviceId = 1
```

Subquery `b` finds all the `ronumbers` that meet criteria 2-4. We then join it with the rows that match criteria 1, and count them.

Comment: Barmar,  unfortunately I was only able to get this query to return one row, when it should have returned 7 in my specific test case.  This is similar to the result from Shadow's suggestion above.  Thank you so much for your time and consideration!

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle? There's no way to paste an image into sqlfiddle.

Comment: Sure thing.  Working on it now!

Comment: Same problem as with my solution: Barmar's query IS expected to return 1 row only: the count of distinct ronumbers matching your criteria.

Comment: Oh goodness, I'm sorry Barmar.  I will run this again and change my fetch rules to get the count result instead of the array of rows.

Comment: @Barmar, I was able to get the correct count perfectly from your query after retrieving the correct fetch instruction.  Thank you so much for your consideration!

Comment: Is there a way that I can give you points even though I gave the acceptance to @Shadow as he/she provided the correct solution first? Thank you.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I have more points than I know what to do with. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A set of data contains only records with service Id 1
B set of data contains only records with service ID not 1 and in set of A having a B.descsvc all records with descsvc of 1 (avg of 3 records each with 1 is 1) 1.

```
SELECT count(distinct A.RoNumber)
FROM ServiceRendered_welr A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT roNumber, avg(descsvc) avgDescsvc 
           FROM ServiceRendered_welr 
           GROUP BY roNumber
           HAVING avgDescsvc = 1) b 
 on A.RoNumber = B.RoNumber
and A.ServiceID = 1
and B.ServiceID > 1
```

Comment: xQbert,  thank you for your input.  Unfortunately I was only able to get this query to return one row when it should have returned 7.  I greatly appreciate your consideration!

Comment: `avgDescsvc = 1` is wrong, it will match if the values are `0`, `1`, `2` instead of all `1`.